# Enumerable.Sum() overflowing

Tags: c#, .net, linq, decompiling

Hey, I'm using the `Enumerable.Sum()` extension method from LINQ to compute hash codes, and am having a problem with `OverflowExceptions` when the code gets big.  I tried putting the call in an `unchecked` block, but that didn't seem to help.

The MSDN documentation for the method says it will throw if the value gets too big, but I checked in reflector and this is all there is:

```
public static int Sum(this IEnumerable<int> source) {
    if (source == null) {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    int num = 0;
    foreach (int num2 in source) {
        num += num2;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Based on this decompilation, I would expect it to either overflow or not depending on the context of the calling code.  Why is it overflowing, and how can I get it to stop?

Comment: This isn't answering the question about overflowing... but if you're using `Sum` to calculate the hash code of an object you're probably not going to create very well distributed hash codes. The typical approach is something like multiply-by-prime-and-left-shift-xor-next in an unchecked context.

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal, but the hash codes that I'm summing (the hash codes of sub-components) are generated in a much better way, so I'm not that worried about it.  (I'm not just adding up `int`s, where small changes would not produce a very different code.)  I assume this isn't something I should go crazy over, but maybe it's more important than I imagine...?

Comment: You could overflow with just two items - if the hashcodes are at or near Int32.MaxValue. Since you're dealing with ints, this doesn't become apparent until you've got lots of items, but with a properly-distributed hash function this will throw exceptions more often than not

Comment: You may go to http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3 and search for "sum("

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is indeed executing in a C# `checked` block.  The problem is that reflector doesn't properly decompile `checked` blocks and instead shows them as normal mathmatical operations.  You can verify this yourself by creating a checked block, compiling the code and then decompiling it in reflector.

You can also verify this by looking at the IL instead of the decompiled C# code.  Instead of the add IL opcode you'll see that the addition occurs with add.ovf.  This is the version of add that throws on overflows

```
L_001a: callvirt instance !0 [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<int32>::get_Current()
L_001f: stloc.1 
L_0020: ldloc.0 
L_0021: ldloc.1 
L_0022: add.ovf <-- This is an overflow aware addition
L_0023: stloc.0 
L_0024: ldloc.2
```

There is no way to get this particular method to not throw on overflow.  Your best options are the following

1. Switch to a larger type such as `long`
2. Write your own version of Sum which does not use checked addition

Answer (score 8):

I wrote this function for generic enumerables. I'd love to hear any remarks about it.

```
public static int SequenceHashCode<T>(IEnumerable<T> seq)
{
    unchecked
    {
        return seq != null ? seq.Aggregate(0, (sum,obj) => sum+obj.GetHashCode()) : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that. As far as I can see, a check for obj==null is missing.

Answer (score 1):

`checked` only applies to expressions in the current block, not any (already-compiled) called method. To use unchecked maths, you'll need to implement your own version of `Sum` inside an `unchecked` block

Comment: So the checked/unchecked distinction is determined at compile time?  I would've expected it to be a runtime, depending on the context, but I guess I would be wrong.

Comment: As JaredPar has answered, it generates different IL commands whether its in a checked or unchecked block; you can't change already-compiled IL