# Disable checking of overflow with Array.Sum

Tags: c#, linq, overflow

There is a Pex4Fun problem that asks the user to write code that finds the sum of an array.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
  public static int Puzzle(int[] a) {
    return a.Sum();
  }
}
```

Pex expects that it can pass {-1840512878, -2147418112} and get back the underflowed number, 307036306, however the LINQ method, Array.Sum(), checks for overflow.

I can't use the unchecked keyword around the method invocation of a.Sum() because the addition happens inside of the method.

Is there any way to disable the checking of underflow/overflow with Array.Sum()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enumerable.Sum() overflowing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208827/enumerable-sum-overflowing)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The specification for all of the [`Enumerable.Sum()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) overloads will throw an `OverflowException` if there is an overflow.  This is not configurable, this is by design.  Just don't use that method.

You can still use LINQ here and use the [`Enumerable.Aggregate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) method instead and not do the checking:

```
public static int Puzzle(int[] a)
{
    return a.Aggregate((sum, i) => unchecked(sum + i));
}
```

Otherwise do it by hand.

Comment: Isn't `unchecked` the default?

Comment: Yes, but defaults can be overridden.

Comment: @Baruch Yes, the operation itself is `unchecked` by default, but in this case, the addition is explicitly made `checked` so we have to work around that. I'm just making it explicitly clear that this is intended to be unchecked. Someone might look at this and get the big-brained idea to switch to `Sum()` not knowing that it's checked.