# Counting value of all properties in generic list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I simply want to add up values from a specific list of custom objects I am currently doing it like this:

```
private int CountChances()
{
    int totalChance = 0;
    foreach(var chance in this.Chances)
    {
       totalChance += chance.Value;
    }
    return totalChance;
}
```

Is there a way to do this faster without the foreach loop? I'm almost certain linq should be able to do this quickly but I cannot seem to find how to do it.

Comment: You want to _Sum_ not _Count_ ;-)

Comment: lol should i give answer `Sum(z=> z.Value)` ? another one gives `Sum(t=> t.Value)`? you know `z` is not same as `t` ;).

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: there's a [third option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33409154/284240): using `Sum(x=> x.Value)`

Comment: Haha verry funny guys :P

Comment: I like `c` most because it's a chances-collection. Also, the `e` often conflicts with `EventArgs e` parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always do:

```
var sum = this.Chances.Sum(c => c.Value);
```

This is shorter and clearer coder. However, performance wise, the `foreach` might be just as fast or even faster.

Note, however, that the implementation of `Sum` uses [checked mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11033880/54981), which can also affect the performance, so if your code is that critical, the `foreach` will be definitely faster.

However, we are talking about very fast code either way, if `Chance` is something like

```
class Chance {
    public long Value {get; set;}
}
```

and we have a list of 10 million items

```
var chances = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Select(i => new Chance{Value = i});
```

on my machine, I'm getting 780ms for the `foreach`, and 1030ms for the `Sum`. So if your code goes nowhere near the million range, you're set with the Sum, as the code is way more obvious.

I.e. since your method is named `CountChances`, there's a chance that a support developer might mistake it's functioning, as it is not obvious at a glance that it actually sums the chances. No such chance with the `Sum` method.

Comment: Would be interesting to know if the difference was the same if you would materialize the query. `var chanceList=chances.ToList()`. Then measure the performance on `chanceList`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - for a materialized query, the result is 393ms vs 723ms in favor of the `foreach`

Comment: @SWeko: still not sure what you have measured. Only one time with 10mio. items or many times? I'm suprised that the difference is so great.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, One run, with a warmup round (in linqpad). I've run it multiple times, and did a manual average. https://gist.github.com/sweko/cddcc3dc97f38e3fbcf0

Comment: @SWeko: these are the results i get from your code, first two are loop and last two are `Enumerable.Sum`: `00:00:00.3780267
00:00:00.3770077
00:00:00.3931983
00:00:00.3159353`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, weird. C# 6 compiler?

Answer (score 5):

You can do that like this:

```
this.Chances.Sum(e => e.Value);
```

Just include:

```
using System.Linq;
```